# How can I make the topology checker plugin ignore very tiny errors?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, topology

I'm a QGIS2.0 user.
Topology checkers is a very valuable for me as a data creator. 
I use this plugin for checking data quality.

But, this plugin finds too much errors include very, very tiny errors.
I have tried to set a "tolerance" for the rule but it does not work well.

Please tell me how to use this function.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 2.0, the Topology Checker tolerance functionality is **not** implemented for any of the available topological rules. See the source code at [Github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-2_0/src/plugins/topology), in particular [topolTest.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_0/src/plugins/topology/topolTest.cpp). It was part of the wish list in the original [merge request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/425). I submitted a bug report ([Bug #9621](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9621)) to the development team asking for the tolerance column to be removed.

Comment: Note: still have the tolerance column in 2017, QGIS 2.18.6. Came here to discover how to use tolerance in Topology Checker and I found your answer.